# PHP send a REST message within body and not as multipart

Tags: php, rest

we have an issue with a PHP client sending a REST / POST message. We receive the message payload as an attachment, while we would expect it in the message content itself.

```
    <http:Accept>*/*</http:Accept>
    <http:Connection>close</http:Connection>
    <http:Content-Length>385</http:Content-Length>
    <http:Content-Type>multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------41eae3cb899c</http:Content-Type>
    <http:Host>JIT</http:Host>
  </tran:headers>
```

While if I send the request using curl like

```
  curl -H "username:XXX"  -X POST -d '<message />' http://myurl.com
```

it works properly, what should I ask to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the content wrong content type, it'd be application / xml